# Regex match and replace various domains

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am unable to find a solution for a simple Google Analytics transformation filter. GA has a slightly limited regex flavor.

The purpose of the filter is to transform subdomain

These possibilities will need to be matched and standardized or kept unchanged

```
example.com        --> example.com
shoesblack.site.de --> shoes.site.de
black.site.de      --> site.de
shoes.site.de      --> shoes.site.de
site.de            --> site.de
site               --> site.de
```

This is the match expression I was able to put together

```
^(shoes\.|shoes)?(black)?(\.)?site(\.de)?
```

and the replace part

```
$1site.de
```

While experimenting with various combinations, I am unable to achieve this in a single transformation. The current example will yield this result. See the missing dot in the first line.

```
shoesblack.site.de --> shoessite.de
black.site.de      --> site.de
shoes.site.de      --> shoes.site.de
site.de            --> site.de
site               --> site.de
```

There is an option to have this in two filters, however I am curious if this could be accomplished in a single transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this should work for you:

**Search String:**  `^(?:(shoes)[^.]*(\.))?.*`

**Replace String:** `$1$2site.de`

Comment: I was testing you regex `^(?:(shoes)[^.]*(\.))?.*`, and it partially works, however the result is not as it should be, I do like the idea though, and will try to play with it more `shoes.site.de --> ok
black.site.de  --> wrong, should be site.de;
shoes.site.de --> ok;
site.de --> ok;
site --> wrong, should be site.de`

Comment: @Jan Put the following in js console: `"black.site.de".replace(/^(?:(shoes)[^.]*(\.))?.*/,'$1$2site.de');` you will see "site.de" returned. Same with `"site".replace(/^(?:(shoes)[^.]*(\.))?.*/,'$1$2site.de');` returns "site.de".  In fact, it's *impossible* that it shouldn't return "site.de" as suffix, because that's part of the replacement string as a literal value. So, you either did something wrong in the setup, or else there's more to it than that, (e.g. perhaps the values aren't what you think they are - maybe has whitespace or "hidden chars" etc..)

Comment: You are right, not sure why it did not work to me... adding a test, all passed `[{"from":"shoesblack.site.de","to":"shoes.site.de"},
{"from":"black.site.de","to":"site.de"},
{"from":"shoes.site.de","to":"shoes.site.de"},
{"from":"site.de","to":"site.de"},
{"from":"site","to":"site.de"}].forEach(function(e){
    console.log(e.from, e.from.replace(/^(?:(shoes)[^.]*(\.))?.*/,'$1$2site.de') == e.to);
});`

Comment: I did find the problem. This code is as well transforming domains, which shall remain unchanged. I did update the question, so it is clear now. Here is the test. `[{"from":"example.com","to":"example.com"},{"from":"shoesblack.site.de","to":"shoes.site.de"},{"from":"black.site.de","to":"site.de"},{"from":"shoes.site.de","to":"shoes.site.de"},{"from":"site.de","to":"site.de"},{"from":"site","to":"site.de"}].forEach(function(e){console.log(e.from,e.from.replace(/^(?:(shoes)[^.]*(\.))?.*/,'$1$2site.de')==e.to);});`